# Fieldvalidator in WinForms

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to put in some field validators to ensure that the text boxes only contain numbers.

However I am unable to find the field validators in the Visual Studio 2008 tools.

I *did* see this when writing a Web Application but not with PC application. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MaskedTextBox` instead or in your validating events, use the `Integer.TryParse` method to see if it's a number, if not, `cancel=true`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBox1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(textBox1_KeyPress);
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar);
    }

}
```